# GWT label widget receiving focus when pressing tab key

Tags: gwt, widget

Current solution:

- user clicks on label and it is switched with a textarea to allow edit
- user can leave edit with tab / enter and textarea is switched back to a label

The problem is the user has to click on the label with a mouse to get into edit mode.
I would like the label to recieve an onFocus event when the user clicks the TAB key and the label is the next widget in line.

Possible soulution (but have not tried yet) to inherit a new widget from the Label widget and implement the TabListener interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a panel called the focus panel. That panel allows widgets that normally dont receive events like keyboard events (e.g., a label is one) to have events.

checkout the docs [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html)

Comment: This probably is it ... will try.